# Load external request file in soapui java API

Tags: java, file, request, soapui

I'm usign SOAPUI API for java and this is a fraction of my code

```
 for (Operation operation : wsdlInterface1.getOperationList()) {
        operationString = WSDL + ":" + wsdlInterface1.getName() + ":" + operation.getName();
        WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = (WsdlOperation) operation;
        // create a new empty request for that operation
        WsdlRequest request = wsdlOperation.addNewRequest("My request");
        request.setTimeout("2000");                 
        requestContent = wsdlOperation.createRequest(true);
        request.setRequestContent(requestContent);
        WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(request), false);
```

Now I need to do something similar to this but loading an existing external request file and I can't find help in the SOAPUI api doc, any help is most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution by myself

This code loads a blank request generated by the soapUI api

```
WsdlOperation wsdlOperation=wsdlInterface1.getOperationByName(operationName);
WsdlRequest request = wsdlOperation.addNewRequest("My request");
request.setTimeout("2000");
String requestContent = wsdlOperation.createRequest(true); // Create a blank request
request.setRequestContent(requestContent);
```

To use an existing Request you need to save that request in a String like this, in my case I get the xml from my database

```
WsdlOperation wsdlOperation=wsdlInterface1.getOperationByName(operationName);
WsdlRequest request = wsdlOperation.addNewRequest("My request");
String requestContent;              
   if(rd.useXmlRequest(artifactId)!=null){ //Verify if exist an xml request for that service
requestContent=rd.useXmlRequest(artifactId); // uses the existing request
   }else{
requestContent = wsdlOperation.createRequest(true); // create a new blank request                       
 }
request.setRequestContent(requestContent); 
WsdlSubmit submit = (WsdlSubmit) request.submit(new WsdlSubmitContext(request), false);
```